# The relation between Drupal Hooks and Modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I don't understand why there are modules. It seems to me that modules are based on hooks. so why they don't just name it custom hooks instead of custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

Because modules are HOLE modules. Module can do a lot of things or not. You can include your own templates in module for some blocks or fields or create your own template for hole site. https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360 :

> A module is a collection of functions that link into Drupal, providing
>   additional functionality for your Drupal installation.